# Tiff workaround for Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tiff

I need to build a data loader to train a CNN for semantic segmentation using tensorflow. The images are 3-channel tiff training images and 1-channel (grayscale) tiff masks.

So far, I followed [this example](https://yann-leguilly.gitlab.io/post/2019-12-14-tensorflow-tfdata-segmentation/). They write a function

```
def parse_image(img_path: str) -> dict:
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(img_path, "images", "annotations")
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(mask_path, "jpg", "png")
    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)
    mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1)
    mask = tf.where(mask == 255, np.dtype('uint8').type(0), mask)

    return {'image': image, 'segmentation_mask': mask}
```

which works well for jpeg and png images. For tiff, however, one has to use `tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image)` which is very limited and it doesn't work in my case. It spits a lot of errors such as

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
```

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67093521/11611246), I could use a package such as `cv2` or `PIL`.

I tried to implement it as follows:

```
import cv2
def parse_image(img_path: str) -> dict:
    # read image
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, tf.uint8)
    # read mask
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(img_path, "X", "y")
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(mask_path, "X.tif", "y.tif")
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path)
    mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, tf.uint8)
    return {"image": image, "segmentation_mask": mask}
```

However, this will only result in

```
TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-46-41b06b3732aa>:6 parse_image  *
        image = cv2.imread(img_path)

    TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'Tensor' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

and I suppose there will be many more problems when using non tensorflow functions in this function.

Since I've seen a few older posts about similar problems with tensorflow and tiff I wondered if in the meantime, there is a workaround? E.g., some custom function that is compatible with the rest of tensorflow and can read tiff data?

Comment: what exactly are you passing to parse_image? It shoudl be a string and you are somehow passing a tensorflow Tensor, that is your problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy It is used as
```train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
   "/some/path" + "/*.tif", seed = 12)

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_image)```

So, yes, a tensor is passed. I don't know how to make this a string, though. Also, I think the ideal solution would be to have a more sophisticated ```.image.decode_tiff``` function. If that's not possible, I'll have to find out how to make a tensor a string. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654238/11611246), for instance, doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still willing to use `opencv` instead, then you can wrap your reading function in a [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function). Inside the scope of the function wrapped in the `tf.numpy_function`, you deal with numpy arrays, so converting the numpy bytestring representation into a regular python string is needed before calling `cv2.imread`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

def parse_with_opencv(image_path):
    return cv2.imread(image_path.decode('UTF-8'))

img_path = ["/path/to/image.tif"]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_path).map(
    lambda x: tf.numpy_function(parse_with_opencv, [x], Tout=tf.uint8)
)
```

Dealing with `tf.numpy_function` is sometimes a bit frustrating, as error messages can be somewhat cryptic.

---

One other option would be to use the [`decode_tiff`](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff) function from the [`tfio` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/io).  It is compatible with TensorFlow operations. Of course it has limitations.

An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def parse_image(image_path):
    filecontent = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(filecontent)
    return img

img_path = ["/path/to/image.tif"]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_path).map(parse_image)
```

Comment: I tried to use ```tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff```, but I had some issues because my images came directly from ```osgeo.gdal``` with some tags unknown to ```TIFFReadDirectory``` (see my question, I had hundrets of errors and warnings because of those tags). I think it would be the best solution if you have "regular" TIFFs, though. Anyways, I switched to PNG in the meantime, which made everything easier. But thanks for your help!

Comment: I read your question a bit too quickly, that's why I added the `opencv` method as well.